# How to remove a locally installed library?

Tags: linux, libraries

I had just compiled and installed [`libc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) locally into my home directory. Sadly, after this, virtually every basic utility like `ls` and `xz` failed to function.

The error message prompted up when executing `ls`:
`ls: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument`

After doing some research on Google, it appeared to me that I have to recompile and relink these basic tools to solve the problem, which seems a bit too tricky. Therefore, I decided to simply removed the `libc` library just installed.

**How do I remove the locally install version of `libc` from `~/lib` and `~/include`?** I had already installed numerous libraries into `~/lib` before installing `libc`, which added another tons of files. As a result, it's all mixed up now.

**Edit:**
I think I could probably solve this by conditionally removing the files based on the last modified time. Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: To me it sounds like you didn't only install files to your home directory. Why would `/bin/ls` and other tools look for libraries there?

Comment: Often makefiles not only have an `install`, but also an `uninstall` target. You could try to run `make uninstall`. Another option is to install it into a known clean directory, e.g. `~/somewhere` and delete those installed files from the first installation.

Comment: @htor I guess it's because I had set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `.profile` to `~/lib`.

Comment: @chenaren Does the problem still occur if you remove the local paths from `LD_LIBRAY_PATH`? You shouldn't mix different version of libraries.

Comment: @htor I actually did that. Now my task is to remove the `libc` files from it, so that I can use other libraries installed in it.

Comment: @Marco Unfortunately, in my case the `uninstall` target is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the unwanted library files with:

`find -mtime -1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

which finds the files and directories modified within one day under the current directory, and removes all of them.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do depends on where the newly installed files were installed and possible on your distro. If you have had configured to install them in `/usr/local/lib` you can remove them and `ls` will find the originals under `/usr/lib` again.

If you have overwritten the location where things are normally installed your installer might not work any more, you would have to try reinstalling libc6 e.g. under Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I don't have the root privilege on this machine. It's the reason why I installed it into my home directory.

Comment: Well in that case you are unlikely to have overwritten the system installed libc. You should be able to remove the `libc6.so` file and if that does not work (`rm` complaining like `ls` see if you can change the library search path (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`) so it will not search in your home directory anymore. Did you install the library or did you 'just' do an `ls` in the directory you have build the libc library?